# After I config the maven home directory, and download the maven source, I can not see the contents

Tags: java, maven

I am using develop java web project under MacOS Sierra, and I configed the Maven home directory in the `/Users/luowensheng/Public`, and the User settings file see my snapshot:

[image]

I am downloading the maven sources,  But in the directory I can not find anything, it is empty yet.

[image]

So, is it some prblem here?

Comment: are you looking for some jar source code ? From your snapshots, maven home should have maven installation.  You need to download and keep it in that directory in order for your tool to work properly. Can you elaborate your question further ?

Comment: Did you notice the "Invalid Maven home directory"? There is no maven installation in this directory. Did you confuse it with the directory you want to put your project?

Comment: @GauravJ, do you mean I should download the Maven? I use IntelliJ IDEA to download the maven source. Can't I download in the `User/luowensheng/public`?

Comment: You should download Maven from here: http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi and install it...

Comment: @khamarbaise, thank you , I have solved this issue, and I will post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the issue, this is caused by my wrong config:

[image]

And then I choosed the path:

[image]